# Populating a NSArray with information from JSON API Call

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Tying to populate an array with objects from an API JSON call.
Tried the following code

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObjectself.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObject objectForKey:@"name"];];       
    NSLog(@"The Array: %@",self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking);        
    [self.tableView reloadData];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

}];

[operation start];
```

The JSON is of the following structure

```
 [

    {
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "53736ca60b9620f12b000000"
    },
    "username": "Admin",
    "name": "Administrator"
    }
]
```

The system crashes when says unknown selector.  When I specify the objectAtIndex:0 it populates the array correctly but then when i try and populate a dictionary which then populates the table view it crashes. Any advice/tutorials that might help the situation

EDIT

To populate the array

```
  operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject objectAtIndex:0]);
    self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObject objectAtIndex:0];
```

To populate the dictionary

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Your title reads populating an `NSarray`, but your question seems to be asking why `objectAtIndex:0` is throwing an error on a dictionary. Dictionaries don't have this method, thats why

Comment: I'm following the tutorial at http://nscookbook.com/2013/12/ios-programming-recipe-16-2-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web-ios-7-and-afnetworking-2-0/ and they populate a array then  NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: This is not the code you have posted. Post the code that generates the error and post the error message. Don't add it in a comment, edit your question and add it

Comment: I've added an answer based off what I think you are trying to do, review it and let me know. If its correct don't forget to upvote / mark as top answer. If its not, add a comment to it

Comment: Downvoted because you did not include the complete exception message and identify the failing line.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the problem is this:

```
self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObjectself.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObject objectForKey:@"name"];];
```

I'm not sure what this code is trying to achieve. If you want to pull out the `name` property and this will only be one element you can hardcode it like this:

```
self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = @[ [responseObject objectForKey:@"name"] ];
```

in this case `@[  ]` is creating an array, and inside we place one element, which is the result of `[responseObject objectForKey:@"name"]`

If there will be many `name`'s that you need you need to then create an `NSMutableArray`, inside the networking callback iterate over the response with a for loop, and use `addObject` method to add an element to the array.